# Autoincrement id increase by 2

Tags: mysql

I use following query to create table `news`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `news_title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `news_detail` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ; 

mysql> desc news;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| news_title  | varchar(500)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| news_detail | varchar(5000) | NO   |     |         |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> insert into news (news_title, news_detail) values ('test','demod demo');



mysql> select * from news;
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | news_title                                                               | news_detail                                                                                                        |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | Advani wants to shift from Gujarat, BJP trying to convince him otherwise | testt |
|  5 | test                                                                     | demod demo                                                                                                         |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

as you see in the `select` query the `id` is increment like `1,3,5,7...`. means it increment by 2. So what is the problem here?

actually in my local, it is increment by 1 and working perfectly. but in my server it creates the problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Why ?***

The auto_increment value can be change with the variable auto_increment_increment.Normally, it’s always 1, but for some weird reason it was set to 2 in my case. I think MySQL Workbench may be involed.

***You can change it be doing one of those :***

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1

SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1;
```

***More information***

*You can find some information [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/mysql-auto-increment-going-2-by-2) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment).*

Comment: Thanks, you provide detailed information.it is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check system variable @@set_auto_increment_increment.

it should be

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

Comment: Thanks `auto_increment_increment` is set `2`.But one quetion, how it change automatically?

Comment: Someone might have changed value accidentally on server. Generally default value is always 1.